# Titanium Alloy - decide which view to show on startup

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm building a small app that requires a login screen. Once the user logged in once, the next time he open the app he'll be already logged in.

In a classic Titanium project in app.js I used to check if the user was logged in, if he was open the main window, and if not - open the login window. but this was when I had control over app.js.

In an Alloy project, I have index.js - which is already a window by itself. How can I create such logic that the correct window will open?

**UPDATE**

So, about 48 hours into Alloy tech... I'm 48 hours smarter.

The most common answer I encountered is to do this logic inside the index controller - which will probably be the most suitable place for such logic in the project pipeline. But I kept thinking that it does has some overhead since I only initialize the index controller to do a simple logic and than, initialize some other controller.

Since Alloy project first compiles to "Classic" Titanium code, looking at the code shows that initialization, and each such controller initialization has it's own code to run as part of it being a controller.

I did found a hack for this... don't know if it's the best thing to do, but it does follow the minimal workflow before executing (just like in classic project):

Tha app/alloy.js file is a place where we can add global functions and objects. From the Appcelerator documentation website:

> The initializer file app/alloy.js can be used to execute some code near the beginning of the application's lifecycle. The contents of this file will be executed right before the initial index.js controller is loaded

In practice, the code from that file compiles to the app.js in the "classic" project. so any code placed there will be placed in app.js.

Taking a look at the "compiled" app.js shows that the final js line executed is the initialization of the index controller. so simply putting your logic in that file will make sure it executes in the app.js, and to prevent the initialization of the index controller, put this line as the last line in alloy.js:

```
if (false)
```

this will make sure that the index initialization never executes.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. You should not define any window in your index file :

```
//in index.xml keep alloy tag
<Alloy>
</Alloy>
```

and then define tow controller (windows) lets say login window & welcome window.

```
//in index.js you can check if the user has logged in or not
var wind=null;
if(logged in ) 
    wind=Alloy.createController('welcome').getView();
else
    wind=Alloy.createController('login').getView();
wind.open();
```

and in login window you have should open welcome window after user log in ...

Comment: seems like it is the probable solution. just seems strange that there is not way to avoid the extra loading of a index controller.

Comment: since index is the starting point of an alloy based app, we cannot avoid the loading of index controller... By the way wen i was working with appcelerator i have noticed that windows make your app more slow. I have come with  a conclusion to do not use only one window in app (index window) inside this window i have defined a view (rootView) and then all other controllers that i have created begin with a View tag and i load them in the rootView wen needed and delete them (remove) when i have finished with them. this solution look like the best one...

Comment: I think having one window and treating each of your screen as a view is a mistake. I consulted a company who got to a similar conclusion on Android devices with "lightweight" windows - and that caused serious bugs in their logic and app. Also, it breaks the normal behavior of the different devices (like navigation control on iOS).